# Find out the number of loaded classes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am working with an enterprise application, It is an search and book portal.
I searched for an item and started jconsole to check the performance on my local machine, It loads the classes for each search and after 2-3 searched the server dies.

I am using jdk1.7 and tomcat7 server.

How can I find out which classes loading for each search ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like an OOM error, you should configure your JVM to generate a heap dump. For example add these to the java commandline options

-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/tmp/dumps

and use a heapdump analyzer such as http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ to understand what is going on.

Best,
Edoardo

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for?

```
java -verbose:class
```

You can specify this option in CATALINA_HOME\bin\setenv.bat (or .sh) file.

for example:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-verbose:class
```

Hope this helps.